# Can $ [0, 1]$ be viewed as an open set?

Tags: general-topology

I just started learning topology and found myself confused about the most basic concept of topological space and open sets.

I read that a topological space is defined for a set $X$ and a collection of subsets $T=\{U_i\mid i\in I\}$ of $X$, if

(1) Both the $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $T$.

(2) $T$ is closed under (possibly infinite) union and finite intersection.

Then $X$ is said to be a topological space and $T$ gives $X$ a topology. The subsets $U_i$'s are called open sets.

I am confused by the following example. Suppose I think $X=R$, and $T=\{\emptyset, R, [0, 1]\}$. It seems the above two axioms are both satisfied, but does this mean that $[0, 1]$ is an open set here?

Comment: Yes.  A set can open according to one topology and closed according to a different topology, there is nothing wrong with that.  The open-ness of a set is not an intrinsic property of the set itself, but rather follows from how we define in that context what it means to be open in the first place which can change according to context.

Comment: In fact, there is the discrete topology, in which all subsets are open

Comment: Your topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is a specific case of "the topology generated by a certain family$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $[0,1]$ is an open set in that topology.

Generally we wouldn’t consider that set open, but that’s because generally we are working with a specific topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by sets of the form $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are two real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The difference lies in the way you *defined* your open sets. Usually one defines the open set $T$ in the case $X = \mathbb{R}$ in the following way:

**Definition**: A set $U$ of real numbers is said to be open if for all $x \in U$ there exists $\delta(x) >0 $ such that $(x - \delta(x), x+\delta(x)) \subset U$.

You defined a different topology on $\mathbb{R}$. In **your** topology $[0,1]$ is open, but if you define $T$ according to the definition I stated $[0,1]$ is not.

Comment: Why do you call it a problem? That suggests there is something wrong with the OP's definition when there isn't. It's non-standard, but that doesn't make it wrong, or even a problem.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist you are totally right, i was thinking about the same thing but couldn't come up with a better expression. edited.